# Overriding AuthorizeAttribute in MVC 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

In my application, I want to redirect the authorized user to update their profile page until they have provided required information. If they update profile, then the `IsProfileCompleted` is set to 'true' in the database.

So, I knows that this can be done by putting check condition in required action of controller.
But I want to do this by customizing the `AuthorizeAttribute`.

I Googled and 'StackOverflowed' for information, but got confused. Please guide me.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

```
public class MyAuthorizeAttribute: AuthorizeAttribute
{
    protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        var authorized = base.AuthorizeCore(httpContext);
        if (!authorized)
        {
            // The user is not authorized => no need to go any further
            return false;
        }

        // We have an authenticated user, let's get his username
        string authenticatedUser = httpContext.User.Identity.Name;

        // and check if he has completed his profile
        if (!this.IsProfileCompleted(authenticatedUser))
        {
            // we store some key into the current HttpContext so that 
            // the HandleUnauthorizedRequest method would know whether it
            // should redirect to the Login or CompleteProfile page
            httpContext.Items["redirectToCompleteProfile"] = true;
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        if (filterContext.HttpContext.Items.Contains("redirectToCompleteProfile"))
        {
            var routeValues = new RouteValueDictionary(new
            {
                controller = "someController",
                action = "someAction",
            });
            filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(routeValues);
        }
        else
        {
            base.HandleUnauthorizedRequest(filterContext);
        }
    }

    private bool IsProfileCompleted(string user)
    {
        // You know what to do here => go hit your database to verify if the
        // current user has already completed his profile by checking
        // the corresponding field
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

and then you could decorate your controller actions with this custom attribute:

```
[MyAuthorize]
public ActionResult FooBar()
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: I am using this example for custom authorize in my mvc app. but, it doesn't redirect it to return url. Did I missed something?

Comment: Once again I am here,above issue has been resolved. I am using session based login and sometime it executes code that should be executed after authorization. I am using static properties for session keys. Can you help me with this?

protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(CurrentUser.UserName) || CurrentUser.UserName == " ")
                return false;
            return true;
        }

Comment: Is this answer compatible with MVC 5 or should we make any changes?

Answer (score 0):

I've taken this code and added some of my own changes, namely to check if the currently logged in user has a session state on the server, they're not as expensive as they used to be!

```
public class CustomAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        var authorized = base.AuthorizeCore(httpContext);
        if (!authorized && !Membership.isAuthenticated())
        {
            // The user is not authorized => no need to go any further
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
}
public class Membership
{
    public static SystemUserDTO GetCurrentUser()
    {
        // create a system user instance
        SystemUserDTO user = null;

        try
        {
            user = (SystemUserDTO)HttpContext.Current.Session["CurrentUser"];
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // stores message into an event log
            Utilities.Log(ex.Message, System.Diagnostics.EventLogEntryType.Warning);

        }
        return user;
    }

    public static bool isAuthenticated()
    {
        bool loggedIn = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated;
        bool hasSession = (GetCurrentUser() != null);
        return (loggedIn && hasSession);
    }
}
```