# A single instance of controller cannot be used to handle multiple requests

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have created my own controller in which i am checking for each request if Session exists execute action otherwise redirect user for login.

Here is my code:

```
public class DefaultController : Controller
{
    protected override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        if (filterContext.HttpContext.Session["User"] == null)
        {
            filterContext.Result = RedirectToAction("Login", "Account");
        }
        else
        {
            base.Execute(filterContext.RequestContext);
        }
    }
}
```

and i am using it in my controller:

```
public class HomeController : DefaultController
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        // DXCOMMENT: Pass a data model for GridView
        return View();    
    }
}
```

when i go to **Home/Index** it is redirecting me to lo-gin according to logic but if use is already logged in (Session exists) it is throwing exception instead of executing that action.

Here is the exception:

> A single instance of controller  cannot be used to handle multiple requests. If a custom controller factory is in use, make sure that it creates a new instance of the controller for each request.

Comment: You could use async await to execute each action in it's own thread. If you have the latest VS and .NET, try adding a new MVC/WebAPI project, the new sample projects default to using async/await. Hope that helps.

Comment: You should write the logic inside a filter instead.

Comment: @KhanhTO in that case i will have to decorate each action explicitly for Session check i need more generic so i am doing this way

Comment: You can register the filter as global if you need it to be applied to all controllers.

Comment: can you elaborate with some sample?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `OnActionExecution` method you are executing the current request: `base.Execute`. The framework later goes and executes again because it doesn't know you executed already.

I have never seen the need to manually call `Execute`. Don't do that. Think of `OnActionExecuting` as an event. You get notified of some event, can hook in but otherwise shouldn't modify how the framework behaves.

Answer (score 0):

Authorization is a cross-cutting concern. You should write your logic as a filter instead.

```
public class CustomAuthAttribute : FilterAttribute, IActionFilter { 

     public void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext) {
         if (filterContext.HttpContext.Session["User"] == null)
         {
            filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(
                                      new RouteValueDictionary 
                                      {
                                         { "action", "Login" },
                                         { "controller", "Account" }
                                      }); 
         }
     } 
}
```

And register it as a global filter in case you need to apply the logic to all controllers.

```
public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
{
    filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute());
    filters.Add(new CustomAuthAttribute());
}
```

Actually, there is already a built-in filter for this job: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.authorizeattribute(v=vs.118).aspx

```
public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
{
    filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute());
    filters.Add(new AuthorizeAttribute());
}
```

Comment: what about overriding built-in filter

Comment: @Ehsan Sajjad: about overriding, there is already a stackoverflow answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19358802/overriding-authorizeattribute-in-mvc-4

Comment: @Ehsan Sajjad: I usually just use the built-in filter without modification.

Comment: but this way i have to decorate actions with that attribute

Comment: @Ehsan Sajjad: by registering the filter as global, it will be applied to all controllers. You don't need to decorate manually.

Comment: @Ehsan Sajjad: In case you need more fine-grained control like `AllowAnonymous` in your custom filter, you have to implement more logic in your custom filter to check for the existence of this attribute.