# Is it safe to create a custom Authrization Attribute by creating a subclass of the AuthorizeAttribute

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-5, authorize-attribute

I have read an article about asp.net mvc security. and it mentioned that the safer approach to create a custom authorization is to create a subclass of the AuthorizeAttribute,because override the AuthorizeCore method, will ensures that I benefit from the features built in to AuthorizeAttribute, and i will not need to worry about detail security implmentation or to create every thing from scratch. as follow:-

```
public class CustomAuthAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute {
  private bool localAllowed;
  public CustomAuthAttribute(bool allowedParam) {
  localAllowed = allowedParam;
 }
protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
 {
   if (httpContext.Request.IsLocal) {
    return localAllowed;
  } 
else {
   return true;
```

Let say i added the CustomAuth attribute instead of the defualt [Authorize] attribute to my action methods. so can anyone advice on the following:-

1. will my custom authorize attribute redirect the user to the login page if the request is not authenticated, as per the web.config setting. or i will loose this feature.
2. is it necessary to check if the request is authenticated inside the custom authorize attribute as follow:-

   if (!httpContext.Request.IsAuthenticated)
        return false;

or this is handled by defualt?

3. can i still use the User , Role and pass them using the custom authorization attribute.

Can anyone advice on this please?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I use a derived `AuthorizeAttribute` as well to handle some situations the base class does not. The problem in your code snippet is that you do not call the base functionality. So in `AuthorizeCore` you need to call `base.AuthorizeCore(httpContext);` instead of checking `httpContext.Request.IsAuthenticated`, unless you want to completely change this behaviour (your 2nd question). Maybe [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19358907/788840) helps.

To answer your first question: yes, as long as you do not override this functionality from the base class.

Question 3: as far as I know your derived attribute works exactly the same as the base as long as you do not override this. But what exactly do you mean with "passing the User and Role"?

Comment: ok thanks for your reply. so i have three main concerns now. First one since i am NOT calling the base.authorizecore what are the features i am going to miss ? Second concern since i am explicitly checking httpContext.Request.IsAuthenticated  so does my code poses a security hole ? third concern if i call base.AuthotizeCore(httpContext) , then i do not need to explicitly call httpContext.Request.IsAuthenticated ?

Comment: 1: take a look at the MVC source code: http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/System.Web.Mvc/AuthorizeAttribute.cs 2: I do not know who's setting `IsAuthenticated`, so not sure if it's safe to call that property. 3: that's correct.