# Middleware for Authencation

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, authentication, asp.net-core

I have created a ASP.NET MVC core application. I just finished creating and logging in a user. Now I'm trying to figure out 
**1.** how to have the user login info saved  
**2.** how to require a user to be logged in to visit the rest of the the site.
For saving the user log info. I was going to use either **Identity** or **Asp.Net.Session**, but seeing has I cant find anything that shows how to require the user to be logged in to visit routes, I’m unsure which option would work best. 
Could someone explain to me how to require authentication before accessing a route, and which of the saving login info works best with that method?

Current Login Example

```
    public ActionResult Login(LoginModel model){
        if (ModelState.IsValid){
            SqlConnect test = new SqlConnect("Data Source=/home/andrew/database.db","Accounts"); 
            var check = test.count(model.UserName,model.Password); 
            if(check){
                // Found in database 
                return RedirectToAction("Index","Home");
            }
        }

        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        return RedirectToAction("Error","Home");
    }
```

Comment: Please don't mix tags from different technologies, as it's confusing. It's not clear from your question if you are asking an ASP.NET Core  MVC or legacy ASP.NET MVC question. Both frameworks. Both framework are generally incompatible as ASP.NET Core (MVC) is a complete rewrite and starts with Version 1.0

Comment: @Tseng Oh, sorry. So its ASP.NET Core (MVC) and not ASP.NET MVC ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't secure routes. When using placeholders (such as in the default route), it is possible that more than one route can reach an action method. These alternate paths are sure to be difficult (nearly impossible) to keep secure as your application changes over time.

So the best option is to secure the *resources* by preventing them from being served. Note that this is also the way security works in ASP.NET, so both ASP.NET and MVC hook into the same mechanism (`IPrincipal` and `IIdentity`) to control both authentication and authorization. ASP.NET Identity and older security frameworks from Microsoft all use this extension point to plug into MVC and ASP.NET.

In MVC, it is the `AuthorizeAttribute` that uses these interfaces to secure action methods. `AuthorizeAttribute` can be used in several ways:

### On Action Methods

```
public class MyController
{
    [Authorize(Roles = "Admin,SuperUser")]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    {
}
```

### On Controllers

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Admin,SuperUser")]
public class MyController
{
    [AllowAnonymous] // All users have access
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    {

    // Only authenticated users in Admin or SuperUser
    // role have access
    public ActionResult Contact()
    {
        return View();
    {

    // Only authenticated users in Admin or SuperUser
    // role have access
    public ActionResult About()
    {
        return View();
    {
}
```

### Globally

```
public class FilterConfig
{
    public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
    {
        filters.Add(new AuthorizeAttribute());
        filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute());
    }
}
```

This means that only authenticated users can access any action method in your application. You can also use roles here like `filters.Add(new AuthorizeAttribute() { Roles = "Foo,Bar" });`. And you can allow specific controllers/actions access to unauthenticated users with the `AllowAnonymousAttribute`.

You can also [subclass `AuthorizeAttribute`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19358802/overriding-authorizeattribute-in-mvc-4) if you have more complex business logic than just Users and Roles.

Comment: OK, but how am i suppose to use identity to save login info ? The only tutorials i find, use pre-made code and I have made all my own thus far.

Comment: The reason why most use premade code is that it is not recommended to roll your own security framework unless you know what you are doing. If you start with the regular MVC 5 template, it automatically generates what the typical application needs, which you can copy over to another application. Read the articles by Brock Allen if you want advice on rolling your own or you can use [his solution](https://github.com/brockallen/BrockAllen.IdentityReboot) as an alternative. It is also possible to extend Identity to save your own fields or use a different database provider than EF.

Comment: Alright, ill give asp.net sessions a try since I understand the concept better.

Comment: Not what I meant - session state is not a replacement for the security framework in MVC. Using the templates that are generated from Visual Studio is the simplest way to implement them (and therefore recommended over rolling your own security if you are not an expert).