# How to redirect to special page when user don't have permision?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, model-view-controller

I register a user then set deactive for it. I want to active user when user fill a form.

```
  await _userManager.AddClaimAsync(user.Id,new Claim("DeActive", "1"));
```

Redirect user to Admin area after register, i want to redirect user to special page in every link menu until user fill special form.

How to set redirect page for all controler action in this area?

Comment: It sounds like you need to implement a custom [authorization attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19358802/overriding-authorizeattribute-in-mvc-4/19358907#19358907)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class MyAuthorizeAttribute: AuthorizeAttribute
{
 protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
 {
    var authorized = base.AuthorizeCore(httpContext);
    if (!authorized)
    {
        // The user is not authorized => no need to go any further
        return false;
    }

    // We have an authenticated user, let's get his username
    string authenticatedUser = httpContext.User.Identity.Name;

    // and check if he has completed his profile
    if (!this.IsProfileCompleted(authenticatedUser))
    {
        // we store some key into the current HttpContext so that 
        // the HandleUnauthorizedRequest method would know whether it
        // should redirect to the Login or CompleteProfile page
        httpContext.Items["redirectToCompleteProfile"] = true;
        return false;
    }

    return true;
 }

 protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
 {
    if (filterContext.HttpContext.Items.Contains("redirectToCompleteProfile"))
    {
        var routeValues = new RouteValueDictionary(new
        {
            controller = "someController",
            action = "someAction",
        });
        filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(routeValues);
    }
    else
    {
        base.HandleUnauthorizedRequest(filterContext);
    }
 }

 private bool IsProfileCompleted(string user)
 {
    // You know what to do here => go hit your database to verify if the
    // current user has already completed his profile by checking
    // the corresponding field
    throw new NotImplementedException();
 }
}
```